# How to render a block provided by a contrib module in a node template

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

I installed [Better Social Sharing Buttons](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_social_sharing_buttons) and I can not understand how to programmatically display the block of this module in `node.html.twig`. I display the blocks created by me like this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $block_entity = Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(6);
  $block_view = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block_entity, 'foo bar');
  $variables['MyCustomBlock'] = $block_view;
}
```

and then `{{ MyCustomBlock }}` in `node.html.twig`.

How to display the block created by the Better Social Sharing Buttons module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak).

> Twig Tweak is a small module which provides a Twig extension with some
>   useful functions and filters that can improve development experience.

Then it's just

```
{{ drupal_block('better_social_sharing_buttons_block') }}
```

Read the docs about [Rendering blocks with Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/rendering-blocks-with-twig-tweak).

> This subject is rather confusing because too many things in Drupal are
>   referred to as "Blocks". So it is essential to understand what kind of
>   block you are going to render. This guide covers three main cases you
>   may deal when rendering blocks in a Twig template.